# Aligning navigation button with text

Tags: html, css

I am developing a mobile-first page and I am trying to align a navigation button to the text and I was wondering if I was doing it correctly. (Ignore the font differences)
This is the result I need to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I have done:

```css
h1 {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: #016008;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#boot {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: #016008;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.navbutton {
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header id="titleHeader">
            <h1><span id="boot">BOOT</span>WORLD<a class="navbutton" href="#navbar">Menu</a></h1>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Menu nav button inside the h1 tag. I separated them, and added the flex to the header container as well as some styling to Menu btn

```css
   body {
   font-size: 16px;
   }

h1 {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: #016008;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#boot {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: #016008;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.navbutton {
    border: solid 3px #000000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}

#titleHeader {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 }
```

```html
         
        <body>
         <header id="titleHeader">
            <h1><span id="boot">BOOT</span>WORLD</h1> <a class="navbutton" 
         href="#navbar">Menu</a>
        </header>
        </body>
```

Comment: But when I run the code you posted the menu button resizes to extremely small font and that happened to me originally when I first tried the flex. See the picture of the result: https://imgur.com/a/tCBCTlO

Comment: Try to add the initial font-size to the body. body {font-size: 16px;}. Your rem values are taken from the main parent (body or html) wherever you write the initial font-size. And look at my code, I added the font-size: 1.5 rem to the .navbutton, have you noticed it?

Comment: Copy entire styles to your code, because acc. to your screenshot you did not copy all styles from menu btn.
.navbutton {
    border: solid 3px #000000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}

#titleHeader {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 }